# In python2.7.11, why can't I remove the fileopen code?

Tags: python, numpy

The `.txt` file holding the data is as follows (source: "datingTestSet2.txt" in Ch.2 [here](https://github.com/pbharrin/machinelearninginaction/tree/master/Ch02)):

```
40920   8.326976    0.953952    largeDoses
14488   7.153469    1.673904    smallDoses
26052   1.441871    0.805124    didntLike
75136   13.147394   0.428964    didntLike
38344   1.669788    0.134296    didntLike
...
```

Code:

```
from numpy import *
import operator
from os import listdir

def file2matrix(filename):
    fr = open(filename)
    # arr = fr.readlines() # Code1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines())        #get the number of lines in the file
    returnMat = zeros((numberOfLines,3))       #prepare matrix to return   
    classLabelVector = []                      #prepare labels return   
    fr = open(filename)  # Code2!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    index = 0
    for line in fr.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        listFromLine = line.split('\t')
        returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]
        classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine[-1]))
        index += 1
    return returnMat,classLabelVector

datingDataMat, datingLabels = file2matrix('datingTestSet2.txt')
```

The result of this function is:

```
      datingDataMat                 datingLabels
40920   8.326976    0.953952           3
14488   7.153469    1.673904           2
26052   1.441871    0.805124           1
75136   13.147394   0.428964           1
38344   1.669788    0.134296           1
72993   10.141740   1.032955           1
35948   6.830792    1.213192           3
42666   13.276369   0.543880           3
67497   8.631577    0.749278           1
35483   12.273169   1.508053           3
50242   3.723498    0.831917           1
...     ...         ...               ...
```

My questions are:

1. When I just remove the Code2(`fr = open(filename)` which above the `index = 0`),
   the result of the function becomes all zeros matrix, and all zeros vector.
   Why can't I remove the Code2? Doesn't the first line(`fr = open(filename)` work?
2. When I just add the Code1(`arr = fr.readlines()`), it is wrong. Why???

   ```
   returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]

   IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can't remove the Code2 line because of this line:

```
numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines())        #get the number of lines in the file
```

In that line you are reading to the end of the file.  Opening it again puts you at the start of the file...

2) Similar to the answer above, if you do a call to readLines() that reads all the lines and moves the file cursor to the end of the file... So if you then try to readlines on the file again, there is nothing to read, hence it fails.

Answer (score 1):

You are at the end of the file. Therefore, your second attempt to read the file content yields nothings. You need to go back to beginning of the file. Use:

```
fr.seek(0)
```

Instead of your:

```
fr = open(filename)  # Code2!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to `readlines` once.

```
def file2matrix(filename):
    fr = open(filename)
    lines = fr.readlines()    
    fr.close()    
    numberOfLines = len(lines)        #get the number of lines in the file
    returnMat = zeros((numberOfLines,3))       #prepare matrix to return   
    classLabelVector = []                      #prepare labels return   
    index = 0
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        listFromLine = line.split('\t')
        returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]
        # careful here, returnMat is initialed as floats
        # listFromLine is list of strings
        classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine[-1]))
        index += 1
    return returnMat,classLabelVector
```

I can suggest a few other changes:

```
def file2matrix(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    returnList = []
    classLabelList = []
    for line in lines:
        listFromLine = line.strip().split('\t')
        returnList.append(listFromLine[0:3])
        classLabelList.append(int(listFromLine[-1]))
    returnMat = np.array(returnList, dtype=float)
    return returnMat, classLabelList
```

or even

```
def file2matrix(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    ll = [line.strip().split('\t')]
    returnMat = np.array([l[0:3] for l in ll], dtype=float)
    classLabelList = [int(l[-1]) for l in ll]
    # classLabelVec = np.array([l[-1] for l in ll], dtype=int)
    return returnMat, classLabelList
```